# Published .NET Core - SQL Server connection error

Tags: sql-server, networking, .net-core, web-deployment

I have published a self contained .NET core 2.1 web API application to a linux server (Lets say it as server 'A'). I have a SQL server database engine running in another server (Lets say it as server 'B'), which serves as the datasource.

Now,

1. I am able to connect the .NET application and SQL server while developing in my local system.
2. I am able to run sqlcmd from 'A', which retrieves data from 'B'.
3. But, when I run the published app in the background (just using a basic command `./MyApp &`) and invoke any one of the API through `curl http://localhost:5000/api/values`, it throws an error on SQL server connection.

The interesting part is that the error is not consistent on all instances. 
It throws 'connection timeout error on post login phase' and 'error receiving data. connection reset by peer' alternatively.

I might be doing a very simple thing completely wrong as well. Any help/discussion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your Connection String in the appSettings.json file and your DbContext setup on startup.cs's ConfigureServices()? Probably the Connection String uses an alias that works on your development computer but isn't known on the published server.

Comment: In the Dbcontext, I have hardcoded it for now and still I face the same issue.